# Setting depth on model serializer forces relational fields to be read_only?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I was looking for a clean way to GET nested model instances, and thought I had found it with the `depth` attribute. But then I found evidence that this sets all fk, m2m, and probably other relational fields to read_only, which causes problems when POSTing new model instances.

The evidence I found was 1) The fields disappeared from the POST form in the browsable api, 2) when I try to create a new model instance from my frontend UI, I get errors about not providing ids for the relational fields (which are non-NULL fields), and most damning 3) the OPTIONS http method returned `read_only: true` for those fields.

So I'm wondering what the most preferred method for patching this up so that I can save new model instances from my frontend UI. Solutions I am considering include:

1) leaving the depth attribute how it is (`depth=2`) and writing a custom serializer that saves the relational fields correctly (in that case would I need to explicitly set the fields to `read_only=False` on the model?),

2) removing the depth attribute and instead write logic in the view that returns nested objects using maybe `select_related` instead, or

3) use 2 serializers, one with `depth=2` for GETs and one un-nested one for POSTs, since I only actually need the nested object when GETing (but I suppose I should probably stay flexible in case that requirement changes)

Comment: See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers about writable nested serializers. Essentially, 2 serializers with a customized `create()` method on the parent.

Comment: @perfect5th if I write the custom create(), will the field magically know it's not read_only anymore? (Reappear as a field in the POST form of the browsable API, and be `read_only=False` in the OPTIONS method), or will I have to explicitly set that on the model?

Comment: Not sure, as I rarely use the browsable API. Why not give it a shot?